# How to Get Datagrid row index to get the previous row's cell value

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I want to change the color of a row if the value of previous row's particular cell's value changes.
I have a Datagrid which binds data from dataset. for eg.

S.NO. Quality Price Cent  MM Size

---

1      AQ     78000 0.001  0.70

---

2      AQ     78000 0.001  0.75

---

3      AQ     76000 0.011  0.76

---

4      AQ     76000 0.012  0.77

---

I want to change the color of the next row if the value of *Price* changes.
I couldnt get the rowindex in Datagrid. I tried with `ItemBound` event
How can I change the row color comparing with its previous value.?

Comment: Please clarify _if the value of Price changes_ Does it mean that your user can edit the rows in your GridView and you want to react to that precise event?

Comment: No. There will not be any user changes in **Datagrid**. Am binding directly from database itself. I want to change the row color while binding itself.

Answer (score 1):

you can access the Rows in the RowDataBound Event.

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
               // do stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: Am using Datagrid. So couldnt use RowDataBound